# How to disable html encoding while saving content by using Froala WYSIWYG Editor in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, froala

I've used Froala editor in my Yii2 application. While saving content to database column question it is added with HTML tags. How can I disable that option, I just want to save the content as it is?

```
 <?php echo froala\froalaeditor\FroalaEditorWidget::widget([
        'model' => $model,
        'attribute' => 'question',
        'options' => [
            // html attributes
            'id'=>'question'
        ],
        'clientOptions' => [
            'toolbarInline' => false,
            'theme' => 'royal', //optional: dark, red, gray, royal
            'language' => 'en_gb' // optional: ar, bs, cs, da, de, en_ca, en_gb, en_us ...
        ]
    ]); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php echo froala\froalaeditor\FroalaEditorWidget::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'question',
    'options' => [
        // html attributes
        'id'=>'question'
    ],
    'clientOptions' => [
        'toolbarInline' => false,
        'theme' => 'royal', //optional: dark, red, gray, royal
        'language' => 'en_gb',
        'entities' => '', // <- this
    ]
]); ?>
```

https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#entities